# Native-base icons not showing on iOS

Tags: ios, icons, native-base

I have a react-native application using expo.
I want to show a logout icon button at the top right corner.

This works on android.  But on iOS (using simulator), the button is just blue, no icon.

Here is my header component :

```
import React from 'react';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import {Header, Content, Button, Text, Right, Body, Left, Icon, Title} from 'native-base';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';

export default class LoggedInHeader extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const {title} = this.props;
        return (
            <Header>
                <Left/>
                <Body>
                    <Title>{title}</Title>
                </Body>
                <Right>
                    <Button onPress={this.onLogOut}>
                        <Icon ios='ios-log-out' android='md-log-out' />
                    </Button>
                </Right>
            </Header>
        );
    }

    onLogOut = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
    }

}
```

And here are my dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "native-base": "^2.11.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-form": "^8.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
```

I found [this issue](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2351) while searching.  It made me believe the I have a dependency issue, so I passed from native base 2.8.0 to 2.9.0 without success.  Even in 2.11.0 I have the same result.

I'm starting to be desperate.  What else should I try ?